# How do I unittest python method that accesses a database?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

```
def insert_env(self, env):
        """Inserts a new environment into ENV_TABLE

        Keyword arguments:
        env -- name of environment to be inserted
        """
        info = {}
        # populate info dictionary
        sql = (
            """INSERT INTO my_table (...) VALUES (...)""")
        try:
            DML(sql, info)
        except oracleException as e:
            logger.debug('dml {0}  resulted in error {1}'.format(sql, e))
```

Here I have a function that populations an `info` dictionary and inserts the values into a table in a database. `DML` is a helper method from another function that has been there for a while now and makes the call to the oracle database, with most of the database info already hardcoded in that function. How can I unittest this function? I can't mock a database because the helper function is hardcoded to access our production db.

Comment: You mock the `DML` call with https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 1):

The help function `DML` is not part of the unit you are testing; mock *it*. The only thing you need to test in `insert_env`, apparently, is that `DML` is called with the appropriate arguments, and that the logger is used if `DML` raises an exception.

The fact that `info`, a local variable in `insert_env`, is never used again after `DML` is called suggests that this is not the full function. There may be more to test, but it is impossible to say with the information given.

Answer (score 1):

First make your sql string a global constant preferably in a second file. Then mock the db calls.

```
# Need to test exception scenario
class oracleExceptionStub(oracleException):
  # bypass constructor
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Test...(unittest.Testcase):
  @mock.patch('path_to_DML')
  def test_insert_valid(self, mock_dml):
    test_env = ...
    expected_info = ...
    insert_env(test_env)
    mock_dml.assert_called_once_with(sql_contant, expected_info) 

 @mock.patch('logger.debug')
 @mock.patch('path_to_DML', side_effect=oracleExceptionStub)
 def test_insert_invalid(self, mock_dml, mock_logger):
   insert_env(..., ...)
   self.assertTrue(mock_logger.called)
```